# Using map/reduce to calculate totals

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach, reduce, higher-order-functions

I want to create a function that does some array manipulation with the following data (see below). Wondering if there's a neat way of doing it with map/forEach or Reduce?

```
function calculateTotalSelections {
        "selections":[
        {
            "item_selected": 1,
        },
        {
            "item_selected": 3,
        },
        {
            "item_selected": 4
        },
        {
            "item_selected": 4
        },
        {
            "item_selected": 1567486585
        },
        {
            "item_selected": 1567486585
        }
    ]
}
```

returns some output like

> item 4 was selected twice
>
> item 1 was selected once
>
> item 1567486585 was selected once

(constraint: the item selection can be unknown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try creating this map via iterations

```
var output = {};
selections.forEach(function(val){
  var value = val["item_selected"];
  output[value] = output[value] || 0;
  output[value]++;
});
```

Now `output` has the frequency of each value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to create an object with the items id as keys and their frequency as values.

```
selections.reduce(function(frequencies, item){
    if (!item.item_selected) return frequencies;
    frequencies[item.item_selected] = (frequencies[item.item_selected] || 0) + 1;
    return frequencies;
}, {});
// --> { '1': 1, '3': 1, '4': 2, '1567486585': 2 }
```